# delete a file through sparkr

Tags: r, azure-blob-storage, sparkr

I want to delete a file in wasb using SparkR for which I got the "unlink" command by referring to the below websites

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/r/ml/ml.R

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html

The command is getting executed without throwing any error but the file is not getting deleted.I checked with permissions also, but it is not working.It would be great if anyone can explain me with examples

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on the same? What do you mean by delete? is it removing from the workspace or some external location?

Comment: The file is present in the wasb storage of azure spark cluster.I want to delete the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to delete a file on HDInsight HDFS using SparkR or R. The method [`unlink`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/unlink.html) is just a method to delete the file or directory on local filesystem, not on HDInsight HDFS with `wasb`. And there is not any API of SparkR to do this. A workaround way is that you can try to use a third-party R package [`rhdfs`](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rhdfs) to do it via `hdfs.rm` method, and the simple code is [here](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/user%3Erhdfs%3EHome). Hope it helps.